# OMPL_ros_interface on Hydro

Tags: ros, turtlebot, ros-hydro, ompl-ros-interface, ompl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'd like to use OMPL library on ROS Hydro to implement OMPL motion planning on Turtlebot. I found the package OMPL_ros_interface but is available in Groovy and not in Hydro. Is there other package for Hydro? Is there alternative to use OMPL library in ROS?

I would avoid MoveIt because I don't use any arm, but I just have to move the base.

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/142241/ompl_ros_interface-on-hydro/) by [Stefano Primatesta](https://answers.ros.org/users/9136/stefano-primatesta/) on ROS Answers with karma: 402 on 2014-03-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

OMPL is integrated into MoveIt. MoveIt is not specific to arms, it's just most commonly used with arms.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2014-03-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Stefano Primatesta](https://answers.ros.org/users/9136/stefano-primatesta/) on 2014-03-24**:
I would use MoveIt with Turtlebot, because I would like to use a new planner for path planning. Is It possible?

I'm following moveIt tutorial, but I'm not able to configure the base motion. The robot can move transversely, which is impossible in reality.